# Laravel join tables and sum amount

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have 2 tables such as users and transactions table.

```
Users
id | name
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name3

Transactions
id | amount | send_id | receive_id
1  |   10   |    1    |     2
2  |   20   |    1    |     2
3  |   15   |    2    |     3
4  |   32   |    3    |     1
```

I wanted to get the amount from transactions by each user. The amount should be the total of receive - send for example name1 is 32(receive) - 30(send) = 2.

Something like

```
[{id:1, name: 'name1', total: 2}, {id:2, name: 'name2', total: 15}, {id:3, name: 'name3', total: 15}]
```

Here is my code of trying and I get max_join_size error.

```
$users= DB::table("users")
      ->selectRaw('users.*, sum(transactions.amount) As total')
      ->join('transactions', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.receive_id')
      ->join('transactions as t1', 'users.id', '=', 't1.send_id')
      ->groupBy('users.id')
      ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
      ->paginate(10);
```

I wanted to paginate and order by the total without calling all the users.
Please help if someone knows the better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eloquent ORM Solution**

I would suggest this solution if and only if you have a models for your tables and you want to use Eloquent ORM, in `User` model we will add two relation for `sent` and `received` transactions then we will append a `total` property to calculate (received - sent) so in your `User` model you will add

```
protected $appends = ['total'];

public function sent()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'send_id');
}

public function received()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'receive_id');
}

public function getTotalAttribute()
{
   return $this->received()->sum('amount') - $this->sent()->sum('amount');
}
```

now wherever you are getting the users you will do

```
$users = User::query()->get()->map(function (User  $user) {
   return [
       'id' => $user->id,
       'name' => $user->name,
       'total' => $user->total,
   ];
});
```

now you can `dd($users);` to see the results

**Another Solution**

instead of using appends we will add a function in `User` model to calculate (received - sent) like so

```
public function sent()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'send_id');
}

public function received()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'receive_id');
}

public function total()
{
   return $this->received()->sum('amount') - $this->sent()->sum('amount');
}
```

now to get `total()` you will do

```
$user->total()
```

Comment: thx for ur solution, using append mean have to call the Transaction everytime i access my user model right?

Comment: Calling the user `total` property yeah will automatically call the `Transaction` model to get the sum of both `sent` and `received` relations.

Comment: By using the append in model, it will call the total accessor automatically.

Comment: Now i got your question right, yes every time you access your `User` model `total` attribute will be called automatically and it will access `Transaction` table, you can use `->makeHidden(['total'])` to not showing `total` but it will be called, because the purpose of `appends` is to be available each time you call `User` model

Comment: Alright, thx. i will see if it is appropriate for me or not. cause i do not feel like calling the transaction everytime i access user model

Comment: I've posted another solution instead of using `appends`.

Comment: You will do it manually not using `orderBy` you will use something like `array_multisort()` to sort the `total` attribute.

Comment: thx for your answer. although its not the best solution for me.